# jasmine parameterized unit test

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, parameterized-unit-test, parameterized-tests

Okay as a C# NUnit guy this might be odd.

But does jasmine allow parameterized unit test?

I am not sure if it goes against the "declare" and "it" to make things readable to non programmers.

I have seen some third party plug ins but they are kind of old, not sure if it has been added to jasmine.
If I am ment to use a plug in

Just to help anyone who finds this in the future, I have been told on jasmine forum There is no first class support for parameterized tests within Jasmine itself.

Comment: You could post the answer you found on the Jasmine forum as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 51):

Based on [piotrek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39617094/443836) and the article [Parameterized testing in Javascript](https://rjzaworski.com/2013/01/parameterized-testing-in-javascript), you could also use the following approach which uses ES6 syntax:

```js
[
  ['abc', 3],
  ['ab', 2],
  ['', 0],
].forEach(([string, expectedLength]) => {
  it(`should return length ${expectedLength} for string "${string}"`, () => {
    expect(string.length).toBe(expectedLength);
  });
});
```

I have tested it with the Jest test framework, but it should work with Jasmine as well.

Comment: It ought to be added that if you have a beforeEach block and possibly an afterEach block this entirely breaks.

If you try and set up a test this way with a beforeEach block Jest throws a 'TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined' exception. 

However all is not lost, it seems to work if you assign the test cases to a variable and iterate over that, as per Dymtro's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909737/1392407

Answer (score 48):

## Better solution (especially if you use TypeScript)

Another solution is to use **Array of Objects** instead of **Array of Arrays**. It fits better if you use some typing system like TypeScript.

---

### Type issue

Imagine you have the following parametrised test:

```js
it('action(value) should reset the forms pool only if value is true', () => {
  [
    [true, 1],
    [false, 0],
  ].forEach(([value, calledTimes]) => {
    spyResetFormsPool.calls.reset();

    component.action(value); // type error #1

    expect(spyResetFormsPool).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(calledTimes); // type error #2
  });
});
```

with TypeScript, it will fail to compile giving two errors:

error #1:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

error #2:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.   Type 'true' is not
> assignable to type 'number'.

That is because TypeScript sees an array of '**number | boolean**'.

We could quickly solve this warning by using some explicit cast:

```js
it('action(value) should reset the forms pool only if value is true', () => {
  [
    [true, 1],
    [false, 0],
  ].forEach(([value, calledTimes]) => {
    spyResetFormsPool.calls.reset();

    component.action(value as boolean); // necessary cast

    expect(spyResetFormsPool).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(calledTimes as number);  // necessary cast
  });
});
```

however this solution is not very nice.

---

### Solution

A better way is to use **Array of Objects**, so the types are correctly handled by default and there is **no need of explicit casting**:

```js
it('action(value) should reset the forms pool only if value is true', () => {
  [
    { value: true, calledTimes: 1 },
    { value: false, calledTimes: 0 },
  ].forEach(({ value, calledTimes }) => {
    spyResetFormsPool.calls.reset();

    component.action(value);

    expect(spyResetFormsPool).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(calledTimes);
  });
});
```

---

Do you want to use `for` instead of `forEach` (I personally find it more readable)? That's also possible:

```js
it('action(value) should reset the forms pool only if value is true', () => {
  for (const {value, calledTimes} of [
    {value: true, calledTimes: 1},
    {value: false, calledTimes: 0},
  ]) {
    spyResetFormsPool.calls.reset();

    component.action(value);

    expect(spyResetFormsPool).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(calledTimes);
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can also move the `it` inside the loop. When I do this, I usually add a `testId` to each object so I can keep track of which tests are failing:

```js
for (const {value, calledTimes} of [
  { testId: 1, value: true,  calledTimes: 1 },
  { testId: 2, value: false, calledTimes: 0 },
]) {
  it(`action(value) should reset the forms pool only if value is true [${testId}]`, () => {
    spyResetFormsPool.calls.reset();

    component.action(value);

    expect(spyResetFormsPool).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(calledTimes);
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print out the actual values in the test name.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following convention to increase readability:

```js
const testCases = [
    {actualValue: true, expectedValue: true},
    {actualValue: false, expectedValue: false}
]

testCases.forEach(({actualValue, expectedValue}) => {
    it(`should be the same given: ${actualValue} and expected :${expectedValue} values`, () => {
      expect(actualValue).toBe(expectedValue)
    })
})
```

You'll see the following test cases to run:

```
Test Results
+ should be the same given: true and expected: true values
+ should be the same given: false and expected: false values
```

Answer (score 5):

i haven't worked with jasmine since a long time but it was pretty easy to add parameterized tests:

```js
  ['abc', 3,
   'ab',  4,
   '',    0].
it('should contain string length', function(string, expected){
   expect(string.length).toBe(expected);
});
```

with just a few lines of infrastructure code:

```js
Array.prototype.it = function(description, testCaseFunction) {
     _(this)
      .chunk(testCaseFunction.length)
      .each(function(innerArray){
                it(description + ' ' + JSON.stringify(innerArray), function(){
                   testCaseFunction.apply(this, innerArray);
                });     
      })
      .value();
};
```

depending on your desired syntax and willingness to change default js objects, you have plenty of options: http://blog.piotrturski.net/2015/04/jasmine-parameterized-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

So I started combining:

- YAML using js-yaml
- jasminejs
- Typescript

to create what I believe are readable parameterized tests like this:

```
import YamlTableReader, {fixtureData, TestData} from "./YamlTableReader";    

describe("TestSuite", () => {
        describe("Real TestCase with Data Fixture", () => {

            // now using tagged template-string to auto convert into YamlTableReader. 

            var testdata = fixtureData ` 

            |   ID  | Value1 | Value2 | Squared |
            |   0   |1       | 1      | 1       |
            |   1   |2       | 2      | 4       |
            |   2   |3       | 3      | 91       |

            `;
            // This actually creates a test for each row of the table above
            testdata.describeEach("Square Test","[ID={ID}]:{Value1} x {Value2} should be equal to {Squared}",
                (row: {Value1: number, Value2: number, Squared: number}) => {
                    expect((row.Value1 * row.Value2)).toBe(row.Squared)
                }
            );
        });
```

Running this will give the following results:

```
Failures:
1) TestSuite 2 Real TestCase with Data Fixture Square Test : [ID=2]:3 x 3 should be equal to 91
  Message:
    Expected 9 to be 91.
```

Sources: https://github.com/deicongmbh/jasmine-param-tests